# Flask render_template not being called after Thread

Tags: python, flask

I currently have an app.route which when it's triggered starts a thread and is suppose to return a template. However it is not currently returning the template, but if I comment out the Thread it does. Is there any work-around for this?

```
@app.route('/start', methods=['POST'])
def start():
    windowname = request.form['windowname']
    Thread(target = runBot(windowname)).start() #when commented out the next line is called
    return render_template('bot.html', isActive = True) #this line isn't being called
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are calling the function in stead of passing it to the thread. try this:

```
@app.route('/start', methods=['POST'])
def start():
    windowname = request.form['windowname']
    Thread(target=runBot, args=(window,)).start() # pass the function, and the argument in the args parameter
    return render_template('bot.html', isActive = True)
```